# Make an IF statement with EVAL command

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

---

Hello everyone

I'm using:

> iMacros v9.0.3 on Firefox 53.0.3 (64 bit) in Windows 10 x64

I'm trying to create a script that I will use it in LOOP mode, extracting pictures from a website. Until here everything is great.

I just want to setup an If statement;

**IF**

```
the value of !VAR1 is a multiple of one hundred
```

> which means (VAR1=100) or (VAR1=200) or (VAR1=300) ... or (VAR1=6600)

**THEN** run this command

```
ADD !VAR4 1
```

**ELSE**

```
ignore and continue
```

I think it's possible to do it with EVAL command, I tried several hours but no result.

Thank you so much.

Comment: No. The correct solution to check whether something is a multiple of hundred is `(x % 100) == 0`. Do not use a statement that tries to compare against every conceivable multiple, do not use `eval`.

Comment: Hi, am I right that your question is about the iMacros own scripting language and not about javascript?

Comment: That's correct, but you can integrate some Javascript statements in iMacros language, for example https://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL  @georg

Comment: Ok, let's put back the javascript tag then.

Comment: Well done, thank you.